# Django cannot execute python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

I got this error right after reinstalling my windows and python accordigly now i cant execute python manage.py rusnerver 
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Looks like your virtual environment is not properly activated or broken.

Comment: You forgot to activate your virtual environment or you might not have the dependencies installed. If you're using pipenv might as well try running `pipenv shell` and then `pipenv install` then `py manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1):

i have faced the same issue after reinstalling the ubuntu , resolved by re creating the virtualenv and re installing the requirements.